# Scaling in linear regression

Tags: regression, statistical-learning

The text is from [Intro to Statistical Learning](http://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Statistical-Learning-Applications-Statistics/dp/1461471370?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=b2873fcd-dac7-4d50-8a4f-ef395872fda3) Page no 380.Can anyone explain the both ideas clearly with an example if possible

> 1) In linear regression scaling has no effect.
>
> 2)In linear regression,multiplying a variable by a factor of c will simply lead to multiplication of the corresponding coeﬃcient estimate by a factor of 1/c, and thus will have no substantive eﬀect on the model obtained

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter for fitted values and residuals if we change the units of measurement of $X$. Consider transforming $X $ by some invertible $k\times k$ matrix $A$, $XA$ (e.g., change months of schooling to years and meters to centimeters when explaining wages).

This is seen as follows,
\begin{eqnarray*}
P_{XA}&:=&XA\bigl((XA)'XA\bigr)^{-1}(XA)'\\
&=&XA\bigl(A'X'XA\bigr)^{-1}A'X'\\
&=&XAA^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}(A')^{-1}A'X'\\
&=&P_{X}
\end{eqnarray*}

What about $\hat{\beta}$? Consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{\beta}^\circ&=&\bigl(\underbrace{A'X'}_{``X'"}\underbrace{XA}_{``X"}\bigr)^{-1}\underbrace{A'X'}_{``X'"}y\\
&=&A^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}(A')^{-1}A'X'y\\
&=&A^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}X'y\\
&=&A^{-1}\hat{\beta}
\end{eqnarray*}
That is, if
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1/12&0\\
0&100
\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{so that}\qquad A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
12&0\\
0&1/100
\end{pmatrix}
$$
in the above example, the effect of a change in the regressors is, sensibly, adjusted accordingly.