# Is it useful or even necessary to standardize independent variables for linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, standardization

When performing a linear multiple regression $ Y = X_1 + X_2 $ is it necessary that $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $ provide the same scale?

When I think of the variables being represented by an orthogonal axis, it shouldn't matter, or ?

[image: Plot]

[Source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html)

Comment: With regularisation, it is necessary in most cases.

Comment: So without it isn't? Regluarisation is only necessary when there are much more variables, right?

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208341/scaling-in-linear-regression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is sometimes useful, but never (IMO) necessary. A linear rescaling of your predictors amounts *precisely* to changing the labels on their axes, in a linear way.

If, for instance, you rescale a predictor such that it has a standard deviation of 1, then you can interpret the corresponding regression coefficient estimate as the change in the dependent variable associated with a 1 SD change in the predictor. This may or may not be more enlightening than leaving your predictors as they are and then interpreting the estimates as the change in the DV associated to a change of 1lb or 1 horsepower.

Comment: (+1) other than the regularised case, I was trying to think of a necessary situation for standardisation, but couldn't come up with a solid reason.

Comment: When there is only on variable, scaling doesn't matter, or? Only in regards to regression, not to mention any functional relationship or so.

Comment: "Doesn't matter" depends on your semantics. Scaling even one predictor will of course change your coefficient estimates (though not $t$ and $p$ value), so in this sense, it does matter. But the exact same thing also holds for scaling multiple predictors.