# Linear regression withouth intercept R

Tags: r, regression, intercept

I'm trying to implement a cost function for linear regression withouth intercept.

I tried understanding what "no intercept" means, but not found anything which could reassure me. I have a dataset that I scale in R with `scaled_data <- scale(data)`.

As I'm scaling, does this mean that my linear regression does not rely on an intercept?

Comment: That means you are fitting a linear function to the data that goes exactly through the origin of the coordinate system. Intercept is where the regression function hits the y-axis and 'no intercept' means hit the y-axis at 0.

Comment: You should probably do something like `lm(cost ~ -1 + predictor1 + predictor2, data)`

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208341/scaling-in-linear-regression/208344#208344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula of the linear regression is,

$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\ldots+\beta_px_p$$

where the coefficient $\beta_0$ is the intercept in the model. This can be written in matrix notation as,

$$y = X\beta+\varepsilon$$

where we are making a slight abuse of notation, because in order to include the $\beta_0$ in this formula, we are writing the vector
$$\beta=(\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_p)$$
and we are writing the matrix
$$X=(1,x_1,\ldots,x_p)$$

So if you want to implement a cost function for a linear regression model without intercept, you just need to remove $\beta_0$ from the vector $\beta$ and remove the vector $1$ from the matrix $X$.

Now, using the already available implementation of linear regression in `R`, this can be done, as suggested in the comments, by setting

`lm(cost ~ -1 + predictor1 + predictor2, data)`

The `-1` there means that you do not want an intercept in the model. **The result of this however is very different from the one you would obtain if you scale the data.**

Scaling the data means that your data is centered, and the intercept of models built using centered data is $0$. In this case, you would obtain the same result with a non intercept model.

But if you build a model without an intercept in a dataset that is not scaled, you will force your regression line to go through the value (0,0), and then the result of a model with intercept and one without intercept will be different.

Comment: Alright so when we wish to write a linear regression model with intercept; given a dataset in matrix form we would add a $\beta_{0}$ column. If we do this and apply `lm()`, we get a model with intercept. If we don't add the $\beta_{0}$ column we get a model withouth intercept? 

Regarding the scaling, it reshapes our data to be oriented around 0 rather then the intercept $\beta_{0}$? And since then $\beta_{0} = 0$, we can simply leave this term out of the equation $\beta = (\beta_{0}=0 => remove), \beta_{1}, ..., \beta_{p}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Got it! Thank you Álvaro! :)