# Proving how scaling of predictor variable in linear regression, affects the fitted coefficient

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, matrix, linear-algebra

In linear regression the OLS solution is given by:

$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY
$$

I want to show that if you scale the $i$th predictor variable by a constant, then the corresponding $i$th coefficient scales down.

In matrix notation I want to show:
If we scale the $i$th column

$$
X^{*}_{(i)} = a \cdot X_{(i)} 
$$

where $X_{(i)}$ denotes the $i$th column, then:

$$\hat{\beta}^*_i = \frac{\hat{\beta}_i}{a}$$

Comment: Ahh of course thank you, I can just plug in a scaling diagonal matrix. Using this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/208344/283493)