# What is the method for calculating stdres in {MASS}

Tags: r, regression, residuals

The documentation for the `MASS` package does not detail the calculation method for the standardized residuals using `stdres()`.  I want to be sure that it matches the method I intend to use:

```
residuals/(stdevres*sqrt(1-hat))
```

Does someone know if this is the calculation applied in this function?

Comment: Hi Sue and welcome to the site. The formula is given in the [book](http://goo.gl/ChYbP5) "Modern applied statistics with S" on page 151: $e_{i}'=e_{i}/s\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}$ which matches your formula. Alternatively, have a look at the source code of the function in the MASS package by typing: `lmwork` without parentheses in `R` after loading the MASS package.

Comment: @COOLSerdash - since you've answered the question, you may as well move it to an answer and get credit for it!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to [Venables and Ripley](http://www.springer.com/statistics/computational+statistics/book/978-0-387-95457-8), pages 151-152, `stdres()` returns $$e'_i=\frac{e_i}{s\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}}$$

However they recommend using *studentized* residuals (in particular for normal probability plots), which are computed by `studres()`. I've expounded [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/99723/44965) their difference.